# Rollback Method Changes in Ruby on Rails with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to rollback a subscription change if it errors, but I am having a hard time figuring out a good way of doing it. I do not want to use web hooks for right now.

Is there a better method for doing this? As you can see, I am trying the events and then rolling each one back manually. I feel like this needs a good refactoring.

```
def change_plan(subscription:, to_plan:, coupon: nil)
  require_args(subscription: subscription, to_plan: to_plan)
  events = []
  begin
    from_plan = subscription.plan
    api_sub = update_subscription_plan(subscription: subscription, to_plan: to_plan,
                                           coupon: coupon, proration_date: get_proration_date, prorate: true)
    events<<'api_updated'
    subscription.update!(plan:           to_plan,
                         coupon:         coupon,
                         item_api_id: api_sub.items.data[0].id)
    events<<'db_updated'
    invoice = create_invoice(subscription)
    events<<'created_invoice'

    invoice = invoice.pay
    events<<'invoice_paid'

  rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    if events.include?('api_updated')
      stripe_sub = update_subscription_plan(subscription: subscription, to_plan: from_plan,
                                             coupon: coupon, proration_date: get_proration_date, prorate: false)
    end
    if events.include?('db_updated')
    subscription.update!(plan:           from_plan,
                         coupon:         coupon,
                         item_api_id: api_sub.items.data[0].id)
    end

    if events.include?('created_invoice')
      void_invoice(invoice.id)
    end
    subscription.errors[:base] << "Upgrade failed, please contact us."
  end
  subscription
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interactor pattern along with the great `interactor` gem that you can find here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor. Interactors are like services, small classes with one purpose, that are called one by one. The gem provides `rollback` method so you can easily rollback any process.

It's worth to mention that there are interactors and organizers. You can treat interactor as a service and organizer as a group of chained interactors triggered in a defined order. In your case you can create `ChangePlan` organizer:

```rb
class ChangePlan
  include Interactor::Organizer

  organize UpdateSubscriptionPlan, UpdateSubscription, CreateInvoice, PayInvoice
end
```

and here are your interactors along with `rollback` method that will revert changes in case of `Stripe::StripeError` error.

```rb
class UpdateSubscriptionPlan
  include Interactor

  def call
    context.api_sub = update_subscription_plan(
      subscription: context.subscription,
      to_plan: context.to_plan,
      coupon: context.coupon,
      proration_date: get_proration_date,
      prorate: true
    )
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => error
    context.fail!(error: error.message)
  end

  def rollback
    update_subscription_plan(
      subscription: context.subscription,
      to_plan: context.from_plan,
      coupon: context.coupon,
      proration_date: get_proration_date,
      prorate: false
    )
  end
end
```

```rb
class UpdateSubscription
  include Interactor

  delegate :subscription, :to_plan, :coupon, :api_sub, :from_plan, to: :context

  def call
    subscription.update!(
      plan: to_plan,
      coupon: coupon,
      item_api_id: api_sub.items.data[0].id
    )
  end

  def rollback
    subscription.update!(
      plan: from_plan,
      coupon: coupon,
      item_api_id: api_sub.items.data[0].id
    )
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateInvoice
  include Interactor

  def call
    context.invoice = create_invoice(context.subscription)
  rescue Stripe::StripeError => error
    context.fail!(error: error.message)
  end

  def rollback
    void_invoice(context.invoice.id)
  end
end
```

```rb
class PayInvoice
  include Interactor

  def call
    context.invoice.pay
  end
end
```

Having such structure you can now call them this way:

```rb
outcome = ChangePlan.call(
  subscription: subscription,
  to_plan: to_plan,
  coupon: coupon
)

unless outcome.success?
  subscription.errors[:base] = 'Upgrade failed, please contact us.'
end
```

You can read more about rollbacks in interactors here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor#rollback. I gave you only pseudocode but having this order allows you to automatically rollback all previous actions when one of the actions will fail. This is the main advantage of interactors.